# how to run shell script in java using Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin

From a long time i am struggling  for with this program. I am having a shell script which accepts parameters as version number and path for the files. then that script creates Zip file with the name of version number congaing all file files to the folder.

I have installed Cygwin on following path **D:/cygwin**.  I am coping required files to same location where cygwin is installed **D:\cygwin\bin**

**Command**

D:/cygwin/bin/bash -c '/bin/test/app.sh 04.10 D:\cygwin\bin\ Test_files

Or Can any one please suggest **how to run shell script in java using Cygwin**.

Rewriting the Problem:-

When i am trying to run following Command in command prompt it gives error

**sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\cygwin\bin\Test_files**

Error:-C:\Documents and Settings\sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\cygwin\bin\Test_files

/usr/bin/app.sh: line 51: lib/lib.sh: No such file or directory

But if i run the same command at

D:cygwin\bin\Test>sh app.sh AK-RD 02.20 D:\cygwin\bin\Test_files

It works fine. Can any one suggest me how to avoid this kind of errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = run.exec("D:/cygwin/bin/bash -c \'/bin/test/app.sh 04.10 D:\cygwin\bin\ Test_files");
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Beware of java excape characters in string literals. I think this is more correct: `D:/cygwin/bin/bash -c \\'/bin/test/app.sh 04.10 D:\\cygwin\\bin\\ Test_files`